# DSN-less ODBC connections are not properly allowing/disallowing write access to SQL-Server tables

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I have an Access DB that makes connections to SQL Server tables with DSN-less ODBC connections.  The tables are in two different databases (Labeler and General_Info) and some connections are intended to be Read-only while others are intended to be Read-write.  I use these connection strings:

```
General_Info database read-write connection:   ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=QDBS-1;UID=Sample-RW;PWD=Sample-RW1;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=General_Info

General_Info database read-only connection:   ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=QDBS-1;UID=Sample-RO;PWD=Sample-RO;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=General_Info

Labeler database read-write connection:   ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=QDBS-1;UID=Sample-RW;PWD=Sample-RW1;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=Labeler

Labeler database read-only connection:   ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=QDBS-1;UID=Sample-RO;PWD=Sample-RO;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=Labeler
```

The problem I’m having is that the General_Info tables **always** act as if they are read-only regardless of which connection I use, and conversely the Labeler tables **always** act as if they are read-write.  I can’t figure out why?

The Sample-RO login has db_datareader, db_denydatawriter, and db_public for both databases
The Sample-RW login has db_datareader, db_datawriter, and db_public for both databases.

I’d be happy for any hints anyone could provide!

Comment: Test in SSMS, and then attach Profiler and examine the connections and requests sent from Access.

Comment: Hi David,  Thanks for the help, but I don't know enough about SSMS to do that or what to look for in the Profiler.